# How to make frame labels like in this plot?

Tags: plotting

How to make the Frame Labels like in this plot

[image]

I mean the Frame Labels are placed above the plot in different rows left and right with different colors. Also besides the plot.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't that work? Have you found similar questions on this site? What did the documentation say about that? Please share your minimum due diligence. You have been around long enough to know how this works. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: If you are using v13+, browse through the docs for the   `MultiaxisArrangement` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** as per the request the following encodes all the requirements

```
Labeled[
 ListPlot[
  RandomReal[10, 100],
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {
    {Column[{Style["Column1", FontFamily -> "League Gothic", 
        FontSize -> 20, Red], 
       Style["Column2", FontFamily -> "Papyrus", FontSize -> 30, 
        Blue]}], None}, {Grid@{
       {
        Style["All masses are below 120 GeV", 
         FontFamily -> "League Gothic", FontSize -> 20, Magenta],
        Style["We need some new results", FontFamily -> "Button", 
         FontSize -> 20, Darker[Yellow]]
        },
       {
        Style[
         "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(h\)]\) vs \
\!\(\*FractionBox[SubscriptBox[\(X\), \(t\)], SubscriptBox[\(M\), \
\(SUSY\)]]\)", FontFamily -> "League Gothic", FontSize -> 20, Green],
        Style[
         "All 120 GeV < some stuff < 150 \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \
\(SUSY\)]\)", FontFamily -> "Academy Engraved LET", FontSize -> 20, 
         Darker[Green]]
        }
       },
     Column[
      {Style["AdS/CFT rules", FontFamily -> "Brush Script MT", 
        FontSize -> 20, Purple], 
       Style["some energy scale", FontFamily -> "SignPainter", 
        FontSize -> 20, Orange],
       Style["compute more things", FontFamily -> "Zapfino", 
        FontSize -> 20, Black]
       }
      ]
     }
    }
  ],
 Grid[
  {{Style["Title: some CERN stuff", FontSize -> Scaled[0.03], 
     FontFamily -> "League Gothic"]}}],
 {{Left, Top}}
 ]
```

> [image: p]

**Original**

Since, for once more, people cannot come up with MWE (minimal working example) the following should be sufficient. The general idea is the use [**`Overlay`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html?v=13.2)

```
lp1 = ListPlot[RandomReal[10, 1000], PlotStyle -> Black, 
   ImagePadding -> 65, Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Some CERN stuff", 
      "still no SUSY @ high energy"}, {"does not matter", 
      "holography rules"}}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["Some CERN stuff probably", 22, "Button", Purple], 
   FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontColor -> Blue, 
       FontFamily -> "League Gothic", FontSize -> 16], 
      Automatic}, {Directive[FontColor -> Orange, 
       FontFamily -> "Brush Script MT", FontSize -> 20], 
      Directive[FontColor -> Black, FontFamily -> "SignPainter", 
       FontSize -> 20]}}, ImageSize -> Large];
lp2 = ListLinePlot[Accumulate@RandomReal[100, 10], PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ImagePadding -> 65, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["Some CERN stuff probably", 22, "Button", Purple], 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Some CERN stuff", 
      "still no SUSY @ high energy"}, {"does not matter", 
      "holography rules"}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, 
     Directive[FontColor -> Red, FontFamily -> "Papyrus", 
      FontSize -> 13]}, ImageSize -> Large];
Overlay[{lp1, lp2}]
```

> [image: cp]

Comment: Hi @bmf thanks for the answer, but this graph is not like the plot I mentioned. First I want the frame labels on the top of the graph two separate labels, just exactly the plot I attached. Also not coloring the frame tickes of the plot

Comment: Besides the blue label on the left, can we add another label with another color say green, and keep the frame ticks black?

Comment: @Dr.phy sorry for the delayed response: please see the update. you should be able to configure the updated answer to your needs. I have written it very explicitly